# how to preview a html file from database to a browser using C#

Tags: c#, database, file, preview

I have HTML code stored in a database and would like to display (render) it onto a view.

I wanted to show it as a normal text page.

```
eg: **HTML:** <h3 style="font-weight: bold">Usage:</h3>
<p style="text-decoration: underline">Viewing of Form -</p>

Should be shown as: Usage:
                    Viewing of Form -
```

I have a button as view and when clicked, it should show me the page.

I am using entity frame work so i have written,

```
string url = ("view.aspx?id = " + page.ID + "&Text=" + page.Text);
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "window.open( '" + url + "', null, 'height=500,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,titlebar=yes' );", true);
```

and i have created a new page view.aspx and tried to use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["Text"])` to render the file.

But i am getting a blank page.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that `page.Text` has a value when it's being rendered?

If you are certain that the value `page.Text` is populated correctly (I'm assuming something like `"view.aspx?id=1&Text=<h3>example post<h3>"`) then you may want to try encoding the string for the URL before returning it to the client.

```
string url = ("view.aspx?id = " + page.ID + "&Text=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(page.Text));
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "window.open( '" + url + "', null, 'height=500,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,titlebar=yes' );", true);
```

Then make sure that you are getting encoded characters in your links on the client.

Comment: Yes page.text has the value while debugging. I tried System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(page.Text) in my view.aspx page but no data is showing up in popup page.And i am not using MVC.

Comment: Actually i am able see normal text file in a new window but i am getting an error for html text display.I think i have to encode decode the html file.what can i do to encode and decode the html file?

Comment: Ok, I deleted my last comment, cause I thought I had a different solution for you, but based on your last comment, perhaps try using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`.  It occurred to me that because you're passing these values around in the query string, the HtmlEncode/Decode may not be encoding the characters correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the use of UrlEncode, please mark as answered if you get a chance :)